# Kubernetes ECONNRESET nodejs

Tags: node.js, networking, kubernetes

I have a front application which is calling a microservice both in nodejs

I do not really understand why from time to time the http call on internal url `http://service.env:3027` is returning `connect ECONNRESET 100.66.156.188:3027`

Should be aprox on 0.1% of the requests but I can not understand why

Comment: How many connections are there per machine? Are there enough resources to handle them?

Answer (score 0):

"ECONNRESET" means the other side of the TCP conversation abruptly closed its end of the connection. This is most probably due to one or more application protocol errors. You could look at the API server logs to see if it complains about something.

It's probably related to clients connected to your frontend just closed the browser in the middle of the request - I wouldn't be to worry about that as long as it stays low in numbers.